# Selective argument with first argument empty in C? expression "var1 ?: var2"

Tags: c, syntax

Sometimes without knowing what it is called, I can't find it with a keyword.
This is another such example. I just saw this express in a C program. (qemu)

```
virt_flash_fdt(vms, sysmem, secure_sysmem ?: sysmem);
```

The called function's definition is like this.

```
static void virt_flash_fdt(VirtMachineState *vms,
                           MemoryRegion *sysmem,
                           MemoryRegion *secure_sysmem)
```

What is the `?:` operator in the function calling? Is it "if secure_sysmem is not null, use it, otherwise use sysmem"? and what is this syntax called? (selective argument with default value?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a GNU extension to the ternary operator; it's equivalent to

```c
virt_flash_fdt(vms, sysmem, secure_sysmem ? secure_sysmem : sysmem);
```

(unless secure_sysmem is a macro with side-effects)

See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html

From that site:

> In this simple case, the ability to omit the middle operand is not especially useful. When it becomes useful is when the first operand does, or may (if it is a macro argument), contain a side effect. Then repeating the operand in the middle would perform the side effect twice. Omitting the middle operand uses the value already computed without the undesirable effects of recomputing it.

So, in the above call, the third argument will be `secure_sysmem` if it is non-NULL, otherwise `sysmem`.

Comment: I see, not call it twice to avoid side effect. Interesting!

Comment: there are no side effects in that code there.

Comment: If secure_sysmem was a macro, there might be side effects. However, it's more likely in this this case it's being used more like JavaScript or C#'s null coalescing operator.